# Python Docstring: raise vs. raises

Tags: python, documentation, docstring

I use the PyCharm IDE which assists with crafting PEP0257-compliant docstrings. It provides two attributes I don't entirely understand the distinction/use between:

- `:raise Exception: exception explanation here`
- `:raises Exception: exception explanation here`

When would I use `raise` as opposes to `raises` in my docstring? Specifically, if a class required an argument that was not provided and raises a `TypeError`, which should be used to document that?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

**TL;DR**

`raises` is used to describe the possible exceptions being raised. `raise` is recognized by [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html) when running autodoc and is the same as `raises`.

**Full Explanation**

PyCharm helps in using a few different styles of docstring comments.

Three which I often use are:

1. [NumPy Format](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#docstring-standard)
2. [Google Format](http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/example_google.html)
3. [Sphinx](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html) (much more than a format)

In all of these there is a special section for `Raises` which you can see in an older version of the PyCharm code tests:

1. [Simple NumPy](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/210e0ed138627926e10094bb9c76026319cec178/python/testData/docstrings/simpleNumpyDocstring.py)
2. [Simple Google](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/210e0ed138627926e10094bb9c76026319cec178/python/testData/docstrings/simpleGoogleDocString.py)

The implementation for `SphinxDocString` we can [see here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/210e0ed138627926e10094bb9c76026319cec178/python/src/com/jetbrains/python/documentation/docstrings/SphinxDocString.java) there there are numerous keywords which can be recognized. Those tags then link to the list of `RAISES_TAGS` which can be found [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/210e0ed138627926e10094bb9c76026319cec178/python/src/com/jetbrains/python/documentation/docstrings/TagBasedDocString.java).

I hope this information is useful.

Comment: Since the SphinxDocString also recognizes `raises`, that is what I am going to use.

Answer (score 20):

You must use `raises` to describe exceptions raised by your method/class.

```
:raises:
    Exception: Explanation here.
```

For example, for a ValueError exception:

```
:raises:
    ValueError: if fft_data is empty.
```

Comment: erik-e's answer is also good.  I like this one because it provides an example.

Comment: Note that the second colon needs to be after the exception name

Answer (score 19):

This works for me in latest version of PyCharm for anyone interested.

```
"""
Some explanations.

:raises WhatEverError: if there is any error
"""
```

Comment: also working in latest intellij too, as of 11/2021

Answer (score 1):

Here's an addition to the previous answers.
If you want to specify multiple raises in one docstring, you have to rewrite the `raises` keywork, as specified in the [Sphinx documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#info-field-lists):

```
"""
Explanation.

:param str par1: The first param
:param par2: The second param
:type par2: integer or None
:return: The returned value
:rtype: int
:raises ValueError: If ...
:raises TypeError: If ...
"""
```

Tested on PyCharm v2022.3.2

Comment: Better use `typing` instead of `rtype`, it's supported by more tools.